# How do objects communicate or send messages to each other in a very basic Rails todo app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails newbie learning oop.

Been studying some oop along with doing Rails tutorials and I don't quite get how oop is working in a basic Rails todo app.

Is it simply that controller objects communicating with model objects?

Comment: Google "rails mvc architecture diagram", images returned are most helpful in understanding communication between the components of the architecture.

Comment: @ImranAli I somewhat have a understanding of the MVC concept but I would like to know how objects interact at a code level.

Comment: [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) show an example of creating a blog, if you haven't seen it before.

Comment: @ImranAli going over that right now. Wondering at what moment an object is communicating as it doesnt mention in a sense that I would like to know.

Comment: Your question is too broad, it's almost impossible to explain your how rails app works in short answer. I highly recommend you to build some simple apps, using tutorials to understand basic concepts - and then ask here more concrete question.

Comment: @unkmas I've been building over 10 apps but don't understand at what point an object is communication to eachother.